# How to know the date interval covered by WEEK function

Tags: mysql, sql, date, summarization

I want to do other 2 columns that shows me, respectively, the first date and the last day of the week grouped.

Currently, I'm summarizing a query by week period. When I run this query, it shows me the results on table:

```
SELECT 
    pc.date,
    CONCAT(YEAR(pc.date), '/', WEEK(pc.date)) as year_week  
FROM pc
GROUP BY CONCAT(YEAR(pc.date), '/', WEEK(pc.date))
ORDER BY pc.date
```

| date | year_week |
| --- | --- |
| 2020-09-02 | 2020/35 |
| 2020-09-07 | 2020/36 |
| 2020-09-17 | 2020/37 |
| 2020-09-23 | 2020/38 |
| 2020-09-28 | 2020/39 |
| 2020-10-10 | 2020/40 |
| 2020-10-11 | 2020/41 |
| 2020-10-21 | 2020/42 |
| 2020-10-28 | 2020/43 |

How can I find the first and last day of grouped week?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `WEEKDAY` function. Demo:

```
select 
 date_add(dt, interval -WEEKDAY(dt)-1 day ) FirstDayOfWeek, 
 date_add(date_add(dt, interval  -WEEKDAY(dt)-1 day), interval 6 day) LastDayOfWeek,
 week(dt) wk
from (
 select '2020-09-02' dt union all
 select '2020-09-07' union all
 select '2020-09-17' 
) t
```

Returns

```
FirstDayOfWeek  LastDayOfWeek   wk
2020-08-30  2020-09-05  35
2020-09-06  2020-09-12  36
2020-09-13  2020-09-19  37
```